# In MVVM - should ViewModels contain view state (such as selected index of a list)

Tags: mvvm

We're having a bit of a debate at my office as to whether or not a ViewModel should contain any state pertaining to a specific view implementation.

An example would be a drop down list in a view having a selected item pointer or index. Would it be against best practice to have that property as part of the ViewModel?

One argument is that the ViewModel should be completely independent of the implementation of any specific view and that ViewModels should be reusable across any amount of views.

The other is that a ViewModel implementation should be tailored to a given view, and have any required view specific state stored within.

Comment: The VM not knowing about the view is pretty much a fantasy we've all agreed to. There are certain things users need to interact with the system. What these things are, and how that interaction takes place, is determined by the view and shapes the VM. True separation only comes with some kind of wrapper that handles this leaking of abstraction between the UI and the VM. For an example, go see how WF4's ModelViewModel wraps POCO vms and instruments them for binding in the UI. Also, you'll never reuse a VM in a different type of application, so tailoring it for a view impl isn't a big deal...